# how to open UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera into a small popup subview

Tags: ios, uiview, uiimagepickercontroller

I am trying to open a `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera` into a small popup subview, however every time I try this it simply goes to full screen camera... This is the first time I have tried using the camera I have read all of the docs in the developers site and I just cannot find anything explaning how to do what I would like to do.

Below is my startCamera method, in which i create a subview, then create the cameraView add the cameraView to the small subview then i load it onto the main UIView.... however as said above it goes full screen everytime :(

any help making this cameraView look like a small popup view would be greatly appreciated.

```
#pragma StartCamera
- (IBAction)startCamera:(id)sender {

    if (isCameraViewLoaded == NO) {
        // Load View for camera
        cameraView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100.0, 100.0, 200.0, 100.0)];
        cameraView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];


        // imagepicker stuff
        // check for rear facing camera to continue
        if( [UIImagePickerController isCameraDeviceAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceRear])
        {
            // load imagePickController into subview
           UIImagePickerController *imagePickController=[[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
            imagePickController.sourceType=UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
            imagePickController.delegate=self;
            imagePickController.allowsEditing=TRUE;
            imagePickController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
            [cameraView addSubview:imagePickController.view];
        }
        else {
            // if there is no camera on the device give warning
            UIAlertView *noCameraAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Incompatible Device" message:@"Sorry, This feature requiers a rear facing camera" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

            [noCameraAlert show];
        }

        // pass camera View to mainview
        [self.view addSubview:cameraView];
        isCameraViewLoaded = YES;
    }else{
        [cameraView removeFromSuperview];
        isCameraViewLoaded = NO;
    }

}
```

Comment: I have not read about AV Foundation yet.. I will do so now..

Comment: You can also check with CameraOverlayView.